# Как создать первое приложение C++/WinRT

Tags: windows, winrt

"Create a Blank App (HelloWinUICppWinRT)
In Visual Studio, create a new project using the Blank App (C++/WinRT) project template. Make sure that you're using the (C++/WinRT) template, and not the (Universal Windows) one."
Где найти пункт меню создание тэмплейта такого типа.
Установил VS 2019 2022, но при выборе создать проект - такого пункта нет.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Когда Вы устанавливаете Visual Studio - то Вы делаете это при помощи Visual Studio Installer.

Эта програма позволяет добавлять/удалять компоненты Visual Studio, устанавливать выходящие обновления и выглядит примерно так:

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

В общем, здесь и нужно покопаться, поставить првильные галочки для того, чтобы появились нужные типы проектов.

Подробно про VSI [написано как обычно](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) на сайте Майкрософта